# AngularJs Data fetch from Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

Hello i use laravel and angular js

im fetching 1 user data from database but i cant show my user data in user profile page

```
id = $rootScope.user.id

$http.get('api/users/'+id).success(function(data){


    $scope.user = data;


})
```

i can see the data in chrome developer tools like that  :

```
data: [{id: "308", email: example, first_name: "example", last_name: "example", website: null,…}]
status: 1
```

but when i want to show data in ng-model like that

```
ng-model="user.first_name"
```

i cant see the data on view

when do this :

```
ng-model="user"
```

return is [object Object]

waiting for help guys , where is my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.user` is an array that contains JSON data. So you can't access `first_name` like `user.first_name`. It should help you.

```
<span ng-repeat="info in user">{{info.first_name}}</span>
```

Comment: Or, more ideally, your API should be returning a single object, instead of an object inside an array.